# limit columns returned in relationnal entity symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

Is it possible to filter an entity and display only few columns in symfony2?
I think I can do a custom query for this, but it seems a bit dirty and I am sure there is a better solution.
For example I have my variable $createdBy below, and it contains few data that shouldnt be displayed in this parent entity such as password etc...

```
/**
 * @var Customer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyCompany\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * })
 */
protected $createdBy;
```

So I need to display my Customer entity, but only containing fields like id and name for example.
EDIT : 
I already have an instance of Project, the entity with my createdBy field, and I want to grab my customer data 'formatted' for this entity and not returning too much fields like password ...

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue you're having is?  Since you control the output you control what to display or not to display.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like expected behavior to me. The doctrine documentation seems to imply that eager fetching is only one level deep.

According to the docs:

> Whenever you query for an entity that has persistent associations and
>   these associations are mapped as EAGER, they will automatically be
>   loaded together with the entity being queried and is thus immediately
>   available to your application.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading

The entity being queried has eager on createdBy so it will be populated.

to bypass you can create a method in your entity repository as following :

```
// join entities and load wanted fields
     public function findCustom()
        {
            return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery(
                    'SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.name ASC'
                )
                ->getResult();
        }
```

### hope this helps you

try this and let me know if it works, you should fill the right repository name

'XXXXBundle:CustomerYYYY', 'c'

```
public function findUser($user_id){

 $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select(array('c', 'cb.id', 'cb.name'))
            ->from('XXXXBundle:Customer', 'c')
            ->where('c.id <> :id')
            ->leftJoin('c.createdBy', 'cb')
            ->setParameter('id', $user_id)->getQuery();
if ($qb != null)
            return $qb->getOneOrNullResult();
        return null;
}
```

Comment: your answer seems to be pertinent, but how do I call this findCustom method as I don't choose to load the associated entity. Lets say that I call my customer associated from a project loaded like that
$project = $em->find('MyProject\Domain\Project', $id); how can I call your custom method in this load automatically to populate my $createdBy with less data?

Comment: i've update the answer, please let me know if it's ok for you

Comment: i've tested your answer, but when I load my project entity, I still have my Cutomer attached to the project with the same structure. I think I will have to manually format all my entities with a foreign key linked to a customer which will be fastidious and boring...

Comment: you can use doctine namedQuery for custom queries : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/tests/Doctrine/Tests/Models/CMS/CmsUser.php

Comment: it seems like a good thing, I will need more time to implement this, I come back once it is tested